# Using e.preventDefault() on <a> elements but allowing click only on link to external document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
    var ulContainer = $(this).closest("li").find("ul");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

I have very simple code: When you click the `<a>` it will slideToggle() `$(ulContainer)` and prevent default action on links. However, is there a way to allow it for the inner links? HTML is like: https://jsfiddle.net/pcq20kjo/

I didn't want to include it all as it's dynamic so not very intuitive but it's basically how to use `e.preventDefault()` but not allow it to propagate to deeper links?

Here is a picture of the fucntionality if that helps: [[image: enter image description here[1]]

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain the javascript in question.  Also your html in the fiddle is invalid, as `div` elements are not allowed to be children of `ul`s.

Comment: The question shouldn't be related to HTML structure. If you have multiple links nested and you use e.preventDefault() on the top parent of those nested links how to you "put back" the prevented behaviour on a nested `<a>`?

Comment: The note about the html is a side note that the markup does not meet web standards.  Also, you do not "put back" behaviour.  You conditionally don't prevent it.

Comment: The server markup is trash I know, just have to deal with it to get paid :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting ALL `<li>` tags, use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to only select the top level direct descendants:

```
$("ul#dropdown-download-links > li > a")
```

Then it won't target the nested `<li>` elements like it currently is.

Comment: No, still not working. See feature on the bottom right: http://wacdev.waclighting.com/product/oculux-architectural-3-5-7/# and add your code to the console. It's hard to explain the problem.

Comment: "Registration has been disabled"

Comment: Thanks for your effort regardless. But here's the real question: The question shouldn't be related to HTML structure. If you have multiple links nested and you use e.preventDefault() on the top parent of those nested links how to you "put back" the prevented behaviour on a nested <a>?

Comment: How to prevent e.preventDefault() from bubbling into nestsed `<a>`'s?

Comment: If you use a proper selector, you wouldn't be binding or doing prevent default on the nested anchors anyway.

Comment: The event is not bubbling from a tag to a tag.  The markup does not have nested a tags, afaik @rec0nstr

Comment: I forgot to include jQuery, here is the exact replica: https://jsfiddle.net/o8fdhke5/1/ -- SO basically hose black squares (which wont be nearly as big) I want to be clicked (they have links). But because of `e.preventDefault()` they don't work as links :(

Comment: Did you look at your browser console? For me it works except the download request is blocked because jsfiddle is on https and your download link is only http.